# Boundary check of a double integral using substitution method

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, multiple-integral

I'm trying to figure out if I managed to do the boundary correct in this exercise, no need to evaluate the integral, just let me know if I got them wrong and how should I do them instead.

$$\int \int _D\:\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dxdy$$ where D: $x^2+y^2\ge 1$ , $0\le y\le x\le 1$

What I have done so far:

$x^2+y^2=1$ circle with the center in $O(0,0)$ and R=$\frac{1}{2}$

$y=0$

$y=x$

$x=1$

$T\rightarrow D':D,$ T: $x=rcos\theta $ , $y=rsin\theta $

So the upper and lower boundary for $\theta$ is $\frac{\pi }{4}\le \theta \le \frac{\pi }{2}$
and the one for r is $\frac{1}{2}\le r\le 1$

Is it correct?

Comment: You should always try to draw a picture instead of trying to it systematically. At least in my personal experience, the systematic method of writing equalities leads to more mistakes than trying to sketch

Comment: Yea, same I did a lot of these type of exercises today and this one was the last one I tried to do it systematically but I ended up drawing the picture anyway, still I couldn't figure out the upper and lower limits till now, need to do a bit more of them in another day I feel like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Please see the shaded region that we need to integrate over.

In polar coordinates, $x = r \cos\theta, y = r \sin\theta$

As $x^2 + y^2 \geq 1 \implies r \geq 1$

$r$ is bound above by $x = 1$. $ \ x \leq 1 \implies r \leq \sec\theta$

Now as $x, y \geq 0, \theta \geq 0$. Also, $x \geq y \implies \tan\theta \leq 1, \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$

So bounds are: $1 \leq r \leq \sec\theta$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$. You have to integrate over $dr$ first and then $d\theta$.

Comment: Thanks again for helping me out! I think I've had enough of doing these type of exercises for today, I really wanted to get used to them but I think I did enough for now haha, my brain can't take it anymore honestly.

Comment: :) you are welcome. As @Buraian said, spending a bit more time on going through the sketch using inequalities will give good insights. When you sketched, were you able to figure out that it was this small region outside the circle? If you figure that out first, the bounds become simpler. If you want to go through this example on how you could have gone about it, we can get into a chat sometime.

Comment: Yes, not the first time after looking more into it I figured it out indeed, and sure would love to sometime. Today I went a bit ham into them if I might say it like that, I wanted to start doing 1-2 exercies on area of the domain using line and double integrals now, and I am looking into the textbook trying to see some examples since the teacher just showed us 2 problems not completed in a rush in like 10 minutes left of the class so it didn't really help.